# Ограничения на INSERT Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Всем привет, столкнулась с задачей наложения условий при вставке сущности c `Hibernate`. Проект на `Spring Boot`, вставляется запись содержащая отрезок времени, необходимо чтобы при вставке следующей записи проверялось чтобы не было наложения промежутка времени на текущий. Как это можно сделать? Пока что я вытягиваю запись с БД и проверяю в коде, нет ли аннотации или другого способа реализовать это на уровне БД? Использую `Postgres`. Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете делать эту проверку триггером, и если период вам не подходит выбрасывать исключение

Comment: какой результат ожидается в случае накладки: ошибка/исключение или обновление "текущей" записи? и насколько большая запись?

Comment: @Ramiz  выбросить исключение

Comment: @JVic спасибо, погуглила - вот что нашла: написать триггер на уровне Postgresql, или использовать EntityListeners и PrePersist. Но как я поняла, если я не хочу делать этого в коде, то мне нужен первый вариант?

Comment: @JVic посоветовалась с коллегой, он сказал использовать Query в JpaRepository который будет проверять - что я и использовала до этого - и это в принципе работало, просто интересно какие еще способы есть

Comment: @Mircella а почему вы не хотите делать эту проверку в коде? Эта проверка - логика вашего приложения и выносить эту логику в БД - не лучший вариант.

Comment: @mit извиняюсь, что отвечаю так поздно, может уже и не актуально - редко захожу. Опыта пока мало - только начинаю работать, а почему вы считаете, что лучше в коде а не на уровне БД? Коллега посоветовал то, что выше, так как не придется все рекорды вытаскивать и проверять - нет нагрузки, так как рекордов там много.

Comment: @Mircella это вопрос архитектуры. Бизнес-логика должна находится на уровне приложения(кода). Причин несколько. К примеру, представьте, что в будущем, кто-то занимается поддержкой вашего приложения (это можете быть даже вы) и для него будет не совсем очевидным то, что в коде идет инсерт записи, а в БД попадает совсем не то, что ожидается, а может и вообще не попадает. Без чтения документации это будет совсем неочевидным - т.е. сопровождение приложения усложняется, особенно если таких штук вы в БД накодите кучу. Естественно, что могут быть исключения, но лучше отделять мух от котлет.